# How to get document item ID of a Document Library given Item Path - using c#?

Tags: 2010, document-library, document-id, path, c-sharp

I can't figure out how to get the item ID of a document library from the crawled or managed properties. So I decided to get it using the item Path which return the document Url allowing to download it.

Given this path I would like to know how to get this particular document item ID. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var file = web.GetFile("FULL_FILE_URL");
var itemId = file.Item.Id;
```

`web` is the `SPWeb` object of the website where your file is kept.

Comment: It is C# code. If you can't work out the rest of it, I can try helping you.